# Why do mirrors not follow brewster's angle?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, polarization

Normally a material will have an angle where the reflected light is completely polarized. Now say we have a mirror (implemented by a conductive silver coating) that reflects most of it's incident light. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/10925 says that this imperfect mirror will be mostly linearly polarized, but not at the brewster angle. Why is this? The derivation for the brewster angle assumes non-magnetic materials, but does not assume non-conductive materials I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have misunderstood the answer to the question you cited.  It says that light reflected from a silvered mirror will be mostly *unpolarized*.  This is true whether the silver is on the front or back surface.  There is a *very* slight polarization due to the less than ideal properties of the silver.

The front surface of a back-surface silvered mirror will reflect highly polarized light, but whatever gets past the front surface will be almost perfectly reflected by the silvered back surface.

Answer (score 0):

Brewster's angle relates the index of refraction to a polarization phenomenon
in reflection from a dielectric (insulator) material.   Most mirrors are
silvered (have a metal coating), and the equivalent dialectric constant
for a metal is ... infinity.   That predicts a Brewster's angle
of 90 degrees, which is geometrically unavailable to an experimenter.

$$ \Theta_{B}  = arctan({\eta_{metal} \over {\eta_{air}}})  = arctan({{\infty} \over 1})$$

The ninety degree angle is simply not a glancing incidence possibility for
a reflection to be observed.   It is not incorrect to say that metallized
mirrors DO follow Brewster's angle.

Comment: i know a perfect conductor has zero resistance but why would it have infinite dielectric constant?

Comment: @roobee - the dielectric constant measures the material's response to an electric field: the response of a metal is (to a good approximation) to completely cancel the field inside the material, i.e. to polarize VERY completely.

Comment: I learned electromagnetism by learning conceptually E and H, and then learning that they follow certain equations called Maxwell's equations, which included a variable called permittivity in one of those equations. That equation being D=epsilon*E, where D being just another variable. Would you be able to explain how from that base I could know that epsilon physically means some quantity that is proportional to "polarization of the metal", and how I would quantify that "polarization of the metal"?

Comment: @roobee  The dielectric constant, epsilon, is the ratio of D (external electric field) to E (internal electric field after material charge rearranges).    For a metal, with the internal E field approximately zero, that ratio is infinite.

Comment: I don't know why D would represent the external E field, but I suppose so long as the variable called D isn't infinity the math works out for making epsilon infinite.

Anyways, since I was asking about a real-life mirror implemented by silver which isn't a perfect conductor, would I be able to see reflected polarized light by looking near the 90 degree angle?